# Exporting map layout to spot color EPS file in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

File export option allows to export to cmyk eps file. I need to export a map layout to spot color EPS file in arcgis 10.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Oddly there seems to be documentation in the Spanish help on how to do this in a page on [Creating a color-mapped .eps file](https://desktop.arcgis.com/es/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/creating-a-color-mapped-eps-file.htm) but it is absent from the English help and says:

> The See Spot Color tool is deprecated at ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.
>   Consider using Production PDF functionality.

There is [Production PDF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/what-is-production-pdf-.htm) documentation that says:

> Production PDF includes the following print production capabilities:
>
> - Spot colors—Provides Spot color support using PDF, including tint control

I think this is part of a Production Mapping paid extension.